# Multiple mailSettings in App.config

Tags: c#

I currently have an App.config like so:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="xxx@xxnn.co.uk">
        <network host="nn.nn.nn.nn"
                 port="25"
                 userName="myname"
                 password="mypass"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

And send MailMessage msg using:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
try { client.Send(msg);
```

But how do I configure 3 or 4 different `<mailSettings>` and pull in the correct configuration at run time?

The mailbox to send FROM will vary depending on `row["Ledger"]` below

```
foreach (DataRow row in accounts.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string cust = row["Account"].ToString();
    string site = row["Ledger"].ToString();
    string mail = row["Email"].ToString();`
```

Comment: Why don't you save those mail settings in the database instead?

Comment: It is a thought, although not my database i can create a table to which I could JOIN ON "Ledger".

Answer (score 3):

Well after a bit more research i came up with the following solution:
in App.Config

```
    <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="Ledgers">
      <section name="1stCompany" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
      <section name="2ndCompany" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
      <section name="3rdCompany" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
      <section name="4thCompany" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <Ledgers>
    <1stCompany>
      <add key="host" value="nn.nn.nn.nn"/>
      <add key="user" value="xxx1@xxx1.co.uk"/>
      <add key="pass" value="password"/>
      <add key="from" value="xxx1@xxx1.co.uk"/>
    </1stCompany>
    <2ndCompany>
      <add key="host" value="nn.nn.nn.nn"/>
      <add key="user" value="xxx2@xxx2.co.uk"/>
      <add key="pass" value="password"/>
      <add key="from" value="xxx2@xxx2.co.uk"/>
    </2ndCompany>
    <3rdCompany>
      <add key="host" value="nn.nn.nn.nn"/>
      <add key="user" value="xxx3@xxx3.co.uk"/>
................................. etc ...........
................................. etc .................
</Ledgers>
</configuration>
```

Then I wrote this method which loops through configSections to match the company names and pull in the mailserver settings

```
private SmtpClient findClient(string site, ref string from)
    {
        // Get the application configuration file.
        Configuration config =
            ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        // Get the collection of the section groups.
        ConfigurationSectionGroupCollection myCollect = config.SectionGroups;

        string host = "";
        string user = "";
        string pass = "";

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        foreach (ConfigurationSectionGroup myGroups in myCollect)
        {
            if (myGroups.Name != "Ledgers") continue;

            foreach (ConfigurationSection mySection in myGroups.Sections)
            {
                string ledger = mySection.SectionInformation.Name.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Site is " + site + "ledger is " + ledger);
                if (ledger.Equals(site, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(
                        mySection.SectionInformation.SectionName)
                            as NameValueCollection;

                    host = section["host"];
                    user = section["user"];
                    pass = section["pass"];
                    from = section["from"];

                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nHost " + host + "\nUsername " +
                                user + "\nPassword " + pass + "\nFrom " + from);

                    client.Port = 25;
                    client.Host = host;
                    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, pass);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return client;
    }
```

The class method seems rather laborious.
I am sure I could go straight to the required section because I know which section I need because it's heading matches the parameter 'site'.
But it is working so is fine for now

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the from address in the message object:

```
msg.From = new MailAddress("fred@somewhere.com");
```

So now all you need to worry about is mapping the `site` value to a from email address. For example if you keep them in the `appSettings` of your `app.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Site1" value="someone@somewhere.com" />
    <add key="Site2" value="someone@somewhere-else.com" />
</appSettings>
```

You can get it like this:

```
public string GetFromAddressBySite(string site)
{
    return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[site];
}
```

As an example, your full code might look like this

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

foreach (DataRow row in accounts.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string cust = row["Account"].ToString();
    string site = row["Ledger"].ToString();
    string mail = row["Email"].ToString();

    //Get your email address, say, from the app.config file
    string fromAddress = GetFromAddressBySite(site);

    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage
    {
        From = new MailAddress(fromAddress),
        Subject = "Hello!",
        Body = "..."
    };

    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(mail));

    client.Send(msg);
}
```

**Note**: You can also store server host, port etc. in a settings file and use them too:

```
var client = new SmtpClient("your.mailserver.com", 25);
```

Comment: I would rather use a config file, so any future change in mail server details only requires the editing of a text file, rather than re-compiling the source code.

Comment: So what is in `row["Ledger"]` then? That is your configuration there.

Comment: The data in DataRow does not contain any mailserver info. row["Ledger"] is just a string with the name of the company sending the email

Comment: Have made a change, but the code to map to a configuration is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pick up your settings from `mailSettings`. You could use your own configuration system, such as a JSON file:

```
{
    "PublicEmailAddress" : { "From" : "external@mycompany.com" },
    "InternalEmailAddress": { "From" : "internal@mycompany.com"}
}
```

You'd write code on startup to read in the configuration and store the configuration in memory, then select the appropriate one based on `row["Ledger"]`.